# Adding a image resource over video file from sd card using ffmpeg or MediaMuxer for android

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, mp4, video-watermarking

I am stuck in this area which I am not comfortable at all to work in.

Here is what I did so far:

- Made an Ubuntu VirtualBox machine
- Downloaded latest ffmpeg version which is 2.3.3
- Compiled ffmpeg to be compatible with armv7-a so in the end I get two folders: include and lib. In include I have the headers and in libs the *.so files (just as in http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/)

[image]

I have created a new android project and made a jni folder and this is how far I went... Even this, with all the struggle being new to linux and compiling took me almost a week to reach.

Adding a watermark in ffmpeg I believe it is done on libavfilter ? I have to dig on this matter, however the original ffmpeg I need to translate into my project is:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -i logo.png -filter_complex 'overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10' output.avi
```

As far as I am studying now I need to do inside jni:

- create a add_watermark.c file in which I need to somehow call the function that does the filter overlay call
- create Android.mk to load this and the ffmpeg needed libraries

  LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

  include $(CLEAR_VARS)

  LOCAL_MODULE := add-watermark

  LOCAL_SRC_FILES := add-watermark.c

  LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -ljnigraphics -lz

  LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libavformat libavcodec libswscale libavutil

  include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

  $(call import-module,ffmpeg-2.3.3/android/armv7-a)
- create Application.mk

  APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a

  APP_PLATFORM := android-8
- run ndk-build and use the generated libraries in my android project.

I really need help on continuing, so every answer is received with great attention and pleasure.

**Later Edit:
Would it be possible to somehow build ffmpeg.exe as a library and call its main with the exact same parameters as the original exe ? I do not want to run ffmpeg as a standalone executable, but have it integrated within the project.** Something like http://www.roman10.net/how-to-port-ffmpeg-the-program-to-androidideas-and-thoughts/ What downsides would this approach have ?

Later edit 2: if this is possible by using MediaMuxer or other APIs added in android 4.3 I am open to it you sample codes are provided. I did look over the MediaCodec and MediaMuxer samples also Grafik and haven't found a proper way to do what I wanted. I prefer ffmpeg approach better if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've successfully achieved what you need. While the theory is quite simple, implementation details make it very hard to get something running.

Your solution starts here:
Download halfninja's project here: https://github.com/halfninja/android-ffmpeg-x264
and follow the instructions to the letter.

Some notes:

- it won't work with newer versions of ffmpeg, e.g. you must use the ffmpeg version the git submodule points to.
- it won't work with newer ndks. You must install the one he's listing there (r5c).

Once you successfully compile, you'll end up with an .so lib that has a "run" method, which you can call to run ffmpeg with the same parameters it gets on the command line.

Also:

- The code above contains a ffmpeg.c file which runs the "main" method, but uses global variables. this means that your code won't be re-entrant. Calling ffmpeg::main twice won't work. You'll have to add initialization code yourself when done, OR create a second library that dynamically loads this library in C and unloads it when done.
- The resulting library will be big as it includes all ffmpeg component, and will bloat your apk. You'll have to change the build file to include only the ffmpeg components you need. e.g. change `configure_ffmpeg` to work with `minimal_featureset`, and `--enable` only the codecs you need.

EDIT:
For mp4 w/ aac use the following  configure_ffmpeg file:

```
--enable-muxer=mp4 --enable-encoder=libx264 --enable-libx264 \
--enable-encoder=h264 --enable-decoder=h264 --enable-demuxer=h264 --enable-muxer=h264 --enable-parser=h264 \
--enable-protocol=file \
--enable-hwaccels \
--enable-demuxer=mov --enable-decoder=aac --enable-decoder=aac_latm --enable-encoder=aac --enable-parser=aac --enable-demuxer=aac --enable-bsf=aac_adtstoasc \
--enable-encoder=aac --enable-parser=aac \
--enable-decoder=mpeg4 --enable-encoder=mpeg4 --enable-parser=mpeg4video --enable-demuxer=m4v"
```

Comment: Thanks Guy, this does not sound promising at all for me. It took me like a week to build the basic libraries, things that everybody says it's very easy. Looking at git it says it was build against ffmpeg 0.9 and now the version is 2.3. Can you please tell me how big was the so file that resulted after you compiled it ? I don't think that I am able to put this through...

Comment: Found this https://enoent.fr/blog/2014/06/20/compile-ffmpeg-for-android/ which pretty much seems to be the same thing, but with newer ffmpeg and ndk, I'll give it a try

Comment: @alin resulting library size depends on what you need. for wav, mp3,mp4avc support you're looking at around 3.5Mb.

Comment: @Alin - also if you need x264, the link you provided won't help you reach your goal. If you actually want x264 (and I strongly recommend it - the difference in quality is not neglegable), I'de start with the link I've provided, to get a working version quickly, then try to upgrade ndk and ffmpeg as a bonus

Comment: The thing is, for now I only want to add the watermark, that's all. The videos I am using are: Codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1) and Codec: MPEG AAC Audio (mp4a). Would default ffmpeg be enough for this ? I'm new to this whole codecs thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Guy for your response. I have tried to build from the second link as I failed to do on yours and I ended with a working ffmpeg library. Hurray. My joy lasted only a little while because the command I needed, failed to work with this error:`Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height.` I thought it was related to audio decoding and I was right, after removing the audio from the file, the command ran fine.

Comment: However, the quality of the video with watermark is pretty low. Is there another way to make the output of a quality close to original? Running the same command to the same video on Windows ffmpeg.exe results in a very good quality output. So there must be a way to handle this using only ffmpeg without x264, right ? And how can I fix the audio problem ?

Comment: @Alin this is probably due to video codec. the visual difference between AVC and "regular" mp4 are distinct. you can take the resulting mp4s and run 'mediainfo' on them, to see their coding information. look for different bitrates and frame sizes for quality differences, as well as different codecs.

Answer (score 1):

ffmpeg is not the easiest library in the world to use. One thing is to use their precompiled executable (as you have done, using ffmpeg), and another completely different is to use their libraries to include multimedia support in your own application.

I recommend you to follow this tutorial:

http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.html

It is pretty old, and some functions are already deprecated or don't exist at all, but Googling a bit will tell you which new functions are the ones you need.

In the tutorial, you will be able to play a video file, both audio and video. The SDL library is requiered also for the tutorial, in order to be able to play the sound through the sound card.

Once you are able to do that, then you will need to overlap the bitmap over the video, which from your calling to ffmpeg, I think it may be done with some kind of filter (I am not sure about this).

Aside, since you have said that you are new to linux, I recommend you to stay on Windows. There are pretty libraries to develop with C++ and Android (i.e. Qt) which are more or less easy to set up and cross compile some basic examples to Android. With those libraries you can build ffmpeg for Android and tell your whole project where your libraries are, so they are automatically included in the .apk.

But furthermore, you can also compile for PC first and see the results until you get what you expect. ONLY THEN, you move to the Android world and do the final testings there.

So summarizing, my workflow would be as follows:

1. Stay in Windows, so you don't get problems related with the OS.
2. Use some IDEs / libraries that allow you to compile C / C++ code for Android (I suggest Qt)
3. Build the ffmpeg libraries for both, PC and Android.
   3b. Build the SDL libraries for both, PC and Android (so you can see and ear the video).
4. Go through the tutorial and set up the basic video player on PC.
5. Add your bitmap modifications and so on PC.
6. Crosscompile to Android and do the final modifications (if needed).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not really fit my purpose. I have seen a lot of tutorials on how to load/play video files but none to what I really need. I have already compiled the ffmpeg libraries and ready to use in the android project, however I can't find any good JNI implementation for the overlay filter implementation.

Comment: Ok, I didn't see that you want to have your program written in Java, and the part you needed is the interface with the native libraries (the JNI). My solution was about writing the entire program in native code (C++ in this case), so it doesn't require any JNI to interface with the libraries, just calling normal library functions.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/rowntreerob/android-ffmpeg/blob/master/Project/src/com/b2bpo/media/notes/RecorderActivity.java

you can try ripping the method 'onFfmpegButton()' from the above , reset the actual CLI parms that you want for ffmpeg, integrated JNI call - not a standalone -  and see whether it  does the merge of the photo that you need.

If u just want info on JNI integration of ffmpeg, see the halfninja project on git and the 'videokit' folder in that project for integration of ffmpeg.main() calls with android JNI.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, this was the only tutorial which helped me do a full build and obtain a working library for my project:

https://enoent.fr/blog/2014/06/20/compile-ffmpeg-for-android/

Comment: So - you don't use x264?

Comment: No, the default video encoder from ffmpeg works great for what I need. The videos are only 10-15 seconds long and they encode quick and good quality.